# Есть ли возможность в angular выводить данные через pattern?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Подскажите, есть ли аналог `.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+([^\d]|$))/g, '$1,')` (jquery) в Angular? 
Цель: вывести число в виде 2 989 298,87 руб.

Comment: + есть ли аналог .toFixed() ?

Comment: выводить куда? просто показать или это значение инпута и его можно прямо в нем редактировать с сохранением форматирования?

Comment: я просто в div вывожу результат вычислений например <div>{{a+b}}</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Частично может помочь фильтр [number](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number), он позволяет указать количество знаков в дробной части, а так же форматирует число в соответствии с локалью *en_US*:

1. дробная часть отделяется точкой
2. группы разделяются запятой.

использовать весьма просто:

```
<div>{{(a+b) | number: 2}}</div>
```

Выведет число с двумя знаками после запятой.

Если нужно форматировать иначе - придется писать свой фильтр, либо воспользоваться одним из многочисленных модулей.

Реализацию фильтра `number` можно [посмотреть в исходниках](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filters.js#L134)

Comment: А если считать и выводить в контроллере, там же будут работать функции jquery?

Comment: @ВячеславЯшников, не понял вопроса. Метод `replace` никак не связан с jQuery - это метод строки и его можно вызвать где угодно.